# unable to use sum in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm facing issues while using sum in terraform

my local variable is as follows :

```
> local.total_output
[
  "150",
  "150",
  "150",
]
> sum(local.total_output)


> Error: Invalid function argument

  on <console-input> line 1:
  (source code not available)
    |----------------
    | local.total_output is tuple with 3 elements

Invalid value for "list" parameter: argument must be list, set, or tuple of
number values.

>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin. All Good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `total_output` is a **list of strings**. It should be list of numbers:

```
[
  150,
  150,
  150,
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, values in the list should be `type` of number. You can convert them with the `for` loop:

```
sum([for str in local.total_output: tonumber(str)])
```

Since `total_output` is a local, probably would be easier just declare it as a list of numbers (no quotes):

```
locals {
  total_output = [150, 150, 150]
}
```